# How to get an HTTP POST request body as a Java String at the server side?

Tags: java, http, post

The getRequestBody method of the HttpExchange object returns an InputStream. There is still much work for correctly read the "Body". Is it a Java library + object + method that goes one more step ahead and returns the body (at the server side) as a ready-to-use Java String?

Answer (score 6):

```
InputStreamReader isr =  new InputStreamReader(t.getRequestBody(),"utf-8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

// From now on, the right way of moving from bytes to utf-8 characters:

int b;
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(512);
while ((b = br.read()) != -1) {
    buf.append((char) b);
}

br.close();
isr.close();

// The resulting string is: buf.toString()
// and the number of BYTES (not utf-8 characters) from the body is: buf.length()
```

Comment: StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

Comment: what is 't' here? InputStreamReader(t.getRequestBody(),"utf-8");

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Spring MVC, you can use the @RequestBody annotation on a method parameter which is of type String. For example.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void doSomething(@RequestBody String requestBodyString) {
    // does something..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Commons IO's `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(InputStream, String)` to do this in one line. (It might not work with HTTP keep-alive though)

Edit:

If you want to go straight to JSON, there are a bunch of Web Service stacks that will do the unmarshalling for you. Try

Spring: http://www.cribbstechnologies.com/2011/04/08/spring-mvc-ajax-web-services-part-2-attack-of-the-json-post/

CXF / JAX-RS: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-JSONsupport

Comment: It is Json. I decipher it and insert the data in a MySQL database.

Comment: Is it a way to go straight to Json? It would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
 InputStreamReader isr =  new InputStreamReader(exchange.getRequestBody(),"utf-8");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
 String value = br.readLine();
```

Comment: Yes, I tried. The problem is that the body does not end with CR/LF. I found a solution by using the read(char[]) method with the content-length and it approximately works. I wonder if it is not a method that performs this reading job to the end.

Comment: You should get the encoding from the HTTP headers, not just assume it's UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

In HttpHandler:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(he.getRequestBody(), "utf-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        int b;
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        while ((b = br.read()) != -1) {
            buf.append((char) b);
        }

        br.close();
        isr.close();
System.out.println(buf.toString());
```