# How to get a POST body request for OkHttp in Java?

Tags: java, http-post, okhttp

I want to get a body request for `POST` http method to get a `request params`. I found this solution [first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393879/how-to-get-a-http-post-request-body-as-a-java-string-at-the-server-side/27692566?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and this one [second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023718/how-to-retrieve-raw-post-data-from-httpservletrequest-in-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but this two did not works for me, because I'm using a `OkHttp`. There is not any `getReader()` method to use or something similar.

How can I get from `OkHttp` POST request body the request parameters?

Comment: Isn't okhttp a client? Why do you want to retrieve the post request body on the client side?

Comment: Yes, but I'm using it with Retrofit-2 on my server side for all http calls. My goal is to get request parameters from this call and use it for some purpose. Maybe you have any idea how to get this params?

Comment: Can you post some code and show where you are having trouble retrieving the body? Both ok and retrofit are client technologies. This doesn't make any sense.